# 301 URL rewrite to remove language parameters when switching store

Tags: magento-enterprise, htaccess

Is it possible to do a custom rewrite to remove the parameters when a user changes language?

For example:

> www.website.com/product?___store=ca_fr&___from_store=ca2014_en

Should become:

> www.website.com/product

I have read about a bit, but I need to do this both ways (so that there is never a parameter for the store change shown in the URL). Is this possible to do? Is it possible through the Magento admin, or does it need to be a .htaccess rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via htaccess, I actually elaborate on this in [a question on server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/801397/htaccess-rewriterule-for-multiple-files-or-path/804186#804186), though the question itself concerned rules after the query string manipulation.

This code excerpt removes 2 keys called `key1` and `key2` (substitute with your chosen keys!) and any value, while retaining the rest of the query string and URL itself :

```
# Activate Rewrite and set the base to the web path
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remove 'key1' from the Querystring, and remove any resulting double &'s
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(?:^|&)key1=(?:[^&]*)((?:&|$).*)     

# %1 = any previous query string, %2 = any following query string   
RewriteCond %1%2 (^|&)([^&].*|$)    

# %1 = matched double & (disgard), %2 = the new query string
# $1 = non greedy match on the URI upto the last /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1?%2  [DPI,E=querycleaned:1]

#Remove 'key2' from the resulting URI, and remove double & again
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(?:^|&)key2=(?:[^&]*)((?:&|$).*)  

# %1 = any previous query string, %2 = any following query string     
RewriteCond %1%2 (^|&)([^&].*|$)    

# %1 = matched double & (disgard), %2 = the new query string
# $1 = non greedy match on the URI upto the last /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1?%2 [DPI,E=querycleaned:1]

#Process any other rules following the query string update here

#Catchall, if query string cleaned but not previously matched, then redirect to clean string
RewriteCond %{ENV:querycleaned} 1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

You'll need to keep an eye out for subsiquent rules (insert at the comment included) and also note that becasue both query string manipuations **are not** declared as `L`ast rules, we have to add a simple catchall to rewrite the URL with the new query string in the case of no further matches.

Also note, I set an enviroment variable for the catchall to detect, as we don't want to rewrite if there's been no query string manipulation :)

Hope it helps!